# jquery perform append/prepend but in the middle, like midpend, or specify pend location?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/6DeAC/

I like to pend some some mark up to a div. But I need the pend to appear in between child elements of my div. Is this possible?

Please see my example below.

```
<div class="bx-wrapper">

    <div class="bx-window">window</div>

    <a href="" class="bx-prev">prev</a>
    <a href="" class="bx-next">next</a>

</div>
```

So I need the pended div to appear here...

```
<div class="bx-wrapper">

    <div class="bx-window">window</div>

    <div id="pendHere">pend</div>

    <a href="" class="bx-prev">prev</a>
    <a href="" class="bx-next">next</a>

</div>
```

Can any one help me with me this, would be much appreciated.

See fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/6DeAC/

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
$('<div id="pendHere">pend</div>').insertAfter('.bx-wrapper .bx-window');
```

Comment: Awesome, did not know of insertAfter function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try $(pend_element).after('element#id or element.class[n]') like so:

```
var elementToPendAfter = $('selector');
```

If your element to pend after has a class name to shorten the number of css declarations or to reuse a single declaration and to eliminate unnecessary css selectors, jQuery will return a literal object array or collection of the elements with the className of your elements. In turn, you can single out any of the elements by calling the variable which holds the className selector and its position in the collection like so:

```
var specificElement = $(elementToPendAfter[2]); // is the third $(element.class)

var pendElement = $(element#id or element.class[n]);
pendElement.after(specificElement);// one line no hassle :)
```

Here is the jQuery api :
[jQuery's after() API](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Make sure to check your HTML in your browsers developers tool after an element has been pended to see if its in the right place.